# ConfigurationManager.AppSettings convert "\n" to "\\n" why?

Tags: asp.net, web-config, appsettings

I have a AppSetting in **web.config**.

```
<add key="key" value="\n|\r"/>
```

When i read it by `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["key"]` it gives **"\\n|\\r"**.
Why ?

Comment: Your question doesn't match your title properly...

Comment: @cjk: why u think so? please read question carefully.

Comment: You've updated it now.  Is it in the debugger you are seeing `\\n|\\r`?

Comment: yes, i checked it by break point.

Answer (score 3):

In the debugger, becuase the backslash is a special character used for things like tabs (\t) and line endings (\n), it has to be escaped by the use of another backslash.  Hence any text that contains an actual \ will be displayed as \.  If you print it out to a file or use it in any other way, you will find your string only contains the one .

This isn't ConfigurationManager doing anything.

Answer (score 2):

The backslash escaping syntax is only recognized inside of string literals by the C# compiler. Since your string is being read from an XML file at runtime, you need to use XML-compatible escaping (character entities) in order include those characters in your string. Thus, your app settings entry should look like the following:

```
<add key="key" value="&x10;|&x13;"/>
```

Because 10 and 13 are the hex values for linefeed and carriage return, respectively.

Like cjk said, the extra slash is being inserted by the debugger to indicate that it is seeing a *literal* slash and not an escape sequence.

Comment: This is supposed to be `&#10;|&#13;` - pound sign and not x.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the same problem with a **string replacement**.
Not beautful.. but works!

```
ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Key"].Replace("\\n", "\n")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string str = "\n";// means \n
string str1 = @"\n";// means \\n
```

From the AppSettings, It seems that when you extract the key's value, @ is internally wrapped.. It is done by the compiler not runtime.